# Combination Graphs in R's ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a combination graph using ggplot2. I would like the graph to look similar to the one below but I don't want the secondary axis, nor do I want the "series 2" showing up in the legend.

Right now I can create a combination graph, see code and data example below, but the issue I'm running into is that my y-axis splits into two different units (0000s and %). I would like to ask for any suggestions that would allow me to display my graph with the y axis reflecting just the `Score` values and the `WARate` value to show up as values below the graphed line, within the plot area.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Type=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
  Quarter=c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q3"),
  Score=c("1360","1330","1345","1200","1215","1230"),
  WARate=c('4%','3.41%','3.39%','4%','3.41%','3.39%')
)
    
df %>% 
  group_by((Quarter)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=(Quarter), y=Score,fill=Type)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(aes(label = format(round(stat(y),0),big.mark=","), group = Quarter), 
        stat = 'summary', fun = sum, vjust = -.25) +
    geom_line(aes(x=Quarter,y=WARate,group = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: This might help: https://biostats.w.uib.no/overlaying-a-line-plot-and-a-column-plot/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I'm looking for.